# How to method chain shift and sample in one line

Tags: ruby, chaining

Say you have an array:

```
a = [2, 5, 8]
```

To get rid of the first element, so you can use `shift`:

```
a.shift # => 2
a # => [5, 8]
```

There is no problem doing `sample` on `a`:

```
a.sample # => 5
```

It doesn't seem possible to do both methods chained. You get

```
a.shift.sample # => undefined method `sample' for 2:Fixnum
```

What would be the most efficient and concise way to do this? The context is iterating through winning_combo arrays for a Ruby tic tac toe program. I do not want to modify the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below :

```
a = [2, 5, 8]
p a.drop(1).sample #=>5
a = [2, 5, 8]
p a.drop(1).sample #=>8
```

Comment: This won't modify the array like `shift` just FYI.

Comment: Yeah I hear you. Totally fine in this scenario, as WINNING_COMBOS multidimensional array is a constant.

Comment: @DavidPardy if you don't want to modify the source array,as you commented please mention it on your post too.